# Is there a clean conversion between system_type_id and SqlDbType?

Tags: .net, sql-server

Aside from building a map manually is there a clean way to convert from system_type_id (as found in the the sys.types view) to the System.Data.SqlDbType enum? It seems like something that would have a built in function but my searches are turning up nothing.

[image]

Comment: enum is just a mask for a number. You need to just send the number to database and treat it like. If that doesn't help then I don't understand what you're asking (or it is not clear enough)

Comment: My issue isn't with converting enums in general... The numeric values of the SqlDbType enum do not correlate at all with the system type ids in SQL... With SqlDbType being used very heavily throughout ADO.Net I'd assumed there was a standard method to map back and forth but so far my searches aren't turning up anything. I can manually map it but I'd rather avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an out of the box way to do what you want. If you look at the source for SqlClient you will see that they do this using a MetaType class that is marked internal.

[.net core source as of this writing](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e0ba7aa8026280ee3571179cc06431baf1dfaaac/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlEnums.cs)